# Filter search results per user custom field

Tags: 7, hooks, search

I would like my site to filter search results based on a Node-reference field of the currently-logged-in-user. I want to limit the search results to nodes that have the same Node-reference field. I am just starting, but stuck on which search hook to use.

Questions:
-which search hook should I use?
-How to access node-reference fields of logged in user AND each node from within this hook?